# How to interaction with a webpage in Java?

Tags: java, http, html, interaction

Now, I am a *beginner* in Java. I have somehow managed to understand the following code.

```
 import java.net.*;
  import java.io.*;

 public class URLConnectionReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL yahoo = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/");
        URLConnection yc = yahoo.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(
                                yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

I actually got that with quite some effort so please do understand I am a beginner. I want to interact with the webpage. From the code, I understood whatever information of the webpage will be simply displayed. I just need your help to advice me wha should I study next.

I want my webpage to go to the webpage, login
Then click on a button
Do a comparision between two columns and report it to me if it isn't equal.

I did do reading on HTTP and I know webinteraction is possible. 
People have code out there that is above my understanding.

I don't know much about inheritence or encapsulation [still learning](incase it is required)

Using the code I provided, is it possible to add on my requirements? 
Cause people are giving one lined codes or 30 lined code...please realize I am not so good in it.

I did do research .I just want someone to give me direction. I am starting to get confused due to so many methods.

I think someone told me  php is easier on this matter, but in php I don't even know anything. (I know it is OOPS language but still)

Any sort of guidance is truely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you actually need to interact with the website then selenium/webdriver is perfect for your needs:

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted

Sample Google search:

```
package org.openqa.selenium.example;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class Example  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new instance of the html unit driver
        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
        // not the implementation.
        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
        element.submit();

        // Check the title of the page
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh yes i know it is perfect! My friend who is in software engineering 3rd year told me about it sadly, he said it may take upto 2 months to understand that...and I got around two months to develop this code! Is it possible to learn in 2 weeks?

Comment: Yes it is definitely possible to learn it in 2 weeks. Secondly it is used widely professionally for automated testing so it is worth learning Selenium, you will also learn other stuff like XML, xPath etc.

Comment: It seems rather interesting...can you login in using selenium?

Comment: like if i get a webpage,like facebook-will it let me enter my details like username or password?

Comment: Yes Selenium is build to do almost whatever a user can do on a web page. It is among best testing frameworks in industry now a days and Login is a very initial and basic test point for any application.

Comment: Yes. You can learn Selenium2 in two weeks. Unfortunately it seems to be unable to keep up with current browser development, which means that unless you're using the chromium web driver, it's unfortunately not going to work very well.

Depending on what *kind* of interaction you want, you could probably get away with using HTMLUnit. Lastly you can use something like PhantomJS.

Comment: Selenium and HTMLUnit are somewhat similar in concept, but Selenium is more mature/robust and has a lot more features.

Note that Selenium encompasses the recording (IDE) plugin for Firefox, which allows you to record tests and the RC/WebDriver automation framework which essentially drives a browser. The two can be used together to make test creation very easy.

The only advantage I could see to using HTMLUnit is that it is less resource intensive, so you could potentially run tests on less hardware, but with Selenium's parallel support even that isn't really true anymore.

Comment: PhantomJS runs perfectly on the command-line, it is suitable as the first layer of smoke testing, whether as part of development workflow and/or in a continuous integration server. Selenium targets multiple browsers and hence it is very useful to ensure cross-browser consistency and carry out extensive testings across different operating systems