# Looking for a good/reliable API for non GUI website interaction

Tags: java, forms, post

Basically I want to gather statistics of searches on various search engines (Google, Yahoo, etc), I want to check how many searches of specific phrases/words wore made and store the information in a file, then use this information for article tagging on my web site. Until now I was doing this by hand using [Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends/explore#cmpt=q&tz=).

Basic requirements are:

- Login
- Manipulating HTML DOM Elements including opening spans/showing forms(basically taking any action needed to reveal the needed form)
- Editing fields of a form(mostly for the data input)
- Submitting forms
- Retrieving relevant information from the webpage after form submission

Java API is prefered but not a must, basically any language will do as long as the API is "transparent" and simple enough so I wont have to spend days learning how to work with it.

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286746/how-to-interaction-with-a-webpage-in-java) which suggested the use of [selenium](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted) for this kind of purpose, it seems good enough to try it, but since its a year old question I was wondering if there are another options.

Comment: Is there a good reason for that vote down?

Comment: Probably because this is a recommendation question which is generally frowned upon: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question

Comment: @Stedy Yeah I guess you right, although I tried to be as specific as possible. Apart from that this info can prove to be generally useful(so I didn't think it deserved a downvote, a comment would have been enough for me to remove/migrate the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://alternativeto.net/software/selenium/) site lists some alternatives to selenium.

That being said, I have used selenium and found it to be quite flexible. You can also set it up in *headless* mode, which would allow the Java application to work without the need of a GUI (can be useful if you have a remote server to do the work, but has no monitor).

The only major issue I had with it (selenium) was that I was using Firefox versions which it still did not support, so you might want to keep an eye on that.

Another note, if you will be using it from a low power device, such as a Raspberry Pi, be sure that add the implicit timeouts.

Comment: Whaa... I cant find the JavaDocs for it. The off page lists only Ruby, Python,  C# and JS. Any chance you know where the Javadocs are?

Comment: Nvm found it. Thak you.

Comment: @DimaMaligin: got around by looking at tutorials and examples and add in some of my own. I was unable to find a comperehensive guide.